# Can I build apps with Mesibo API and .NET technology?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, api, mesibo

I want to use Mesibo API to build apps with feature as video call, chat, capture, conferencing, send file .. but my team's using .NET technology as .NET MVC, .NET Core ... so I confuse on this solution.
Could you explan can I build apps with Mesibo API  and .NET technology?

Thanks All,

Hai

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried, but a quick search on google gives me this link which says it is possible to use javascript API from ASP.NET MVC.

http://www.codedigest.com/posts/35/adding-javascript-in-aspnet-mvc-views

If that's the case, you should be able to use mesibo Javascript APIs from your ASP.NET app,

https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/js/

You can try and update here.